# Setup the .ssh/config file

Tags: ssh, aws

I created a server (do we say create a server or a host?) on Amazon Web Server. I'd like to get access directly from my computer. Actually, I need to do something like `ssh -i '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' something.compute.amazonaws.com` to connect the server. I'd like I could just do something like `ssh spinningatinfinity` instead. I think I could set up my `config` file in the `.ssh` directory :

```
Host spinningatinfinity
    Hostname something.compute.amazonaws.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

How could I configure the `config` file to replace `ssh -i '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' something.compute.amazonaws.com` to `ssh spinningatinfinity`? I'll probably need a proxy command, but I can't see how to use it.

Answer (score 4):

What you have is pretty close to what I have in mind. Specifically, you can try something like this:

```
Host spinningatinfinity
  HostName something.compute.amazonaws.com
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Note that the default username for a Ubuntu image in a AWS EC2 instance is `ubuntu`, so you need to specify that as an argument for the `User` keyword to avoid typing it at the command line. In addition, if you use AWS to generate your SSH keys, the private key is actually a `.pem` file, so adjust `IdentityFile` accordingly if that is true for you. Now you can SSH just using:

```
ssh spinningatinfinity
```

Comment: Yes, I know it is a `.pem` file, but instead, I prefer to use my own id_rsa.pub file. It works well for me, so why not..

Comment: @J.Doe That's fine, you can use your `id_rsa` and upload its public key to your AWS EC2 instance.

Comment: It is a little bit weird, because it is fine with `ssh -i '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' something.compute.amazonaws.com`, but it didn't work with `ssh spinningatinfinity` even with you answer. Why?

Comment: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname something.compute.amazonaws.com: Name or service not known` is the error.

Comment: @J.Doe Make sure the hostname is correct; I think it changes every time you restart the instance. Other than that, I don't know why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Yet, I copy/paste the one from my command into my config file, so it should be good, right?

Comment: `something.compute.amazonaws.com` is considered to be the public DNS. Does the hostname is the same as the public DNS?

Comment: @J.Doe Yeah, same.

Comment: How does the public key is related to my public DNS? `IdentifyFile` is for the  `id_rsa` file.